# react native redux saga does not run

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, redux-saga

Why is my saga not running ? I dont get the message " console.log('hi') ".

sagaAuth.js

```
import { all, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* hello() {
  while(true) {
    console.log('hi')
  }
};

export default function*() {
  yield all([hello])
};
```

rootSaga.js

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import authSaga from './saga/auth';

export default function* () {
  yield all([authSaga]);
}
```

store

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducers from './reducers';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import saga from './saga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware({ thunk: false }).concat(sagaMiddleware)
});

sagaMiddleware.run(saga);

export default store;
```

..............................
..............................

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your sagas you put into `all` in the `fork` effect like this:

```js
import {all, fork} from 'redux-saga/effects';

export default function* () {
  yield all([fork(authSaga)]);
}
...
export default function*() {
  yield all([fork(hello)]);
};
```

Also avoid infinite loops without a blocking effect inside of it. The console.log as you have it right now might freeze your app before you open your devtools.